# Periodic task in a Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, task, kernel-module, gpio

Currently I am developing GPIO kernel module for friendlyarm Linux 2.6.32.2 (mini2440). I am from electronics background and new to Linux.

The kernel module loaded at start-up and the related device file is located in `/dev` as `gpiofreq`.

At first time writing to device file, GPIO pin toggles continuously at 50kHz. At second time writing it stop toggling. At third time, it starts again, and so on.

I have wrote separate kernel module to generate freq. but CPU freezes after writing device file at first time. The terminal prompt is shown but I can not run any command afterwards.

Here is the code-snippet:

```c
//calling function which generates continuous freq at gpio

static int send_freq(void *arg)
{
    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    for(;;)
    {
        gpio_set_value(192,1);
        udelay(10);
        gpio_set_value(192,0);
        udelay(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the device write code,
which start or stop with any data written to device file.

```c
if(toggle==0)
{
       printk("Starting Freq.\n");
       task=kthread_run(&send_freq,(void *)freq,"START");
       toggle=1;
}
else
{
       printk("Operation Terminated.\n");
       i = kthread_stop(task);
       toggle=0;
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you want your task to run entirely *inside the kernel*? Common wisdom is to have a user-level helper process....

Comment: because i want the freq upto 100kHz. i already tried a shell-script which gives me toggle frequency around 750 Hz. and also a c program which gives me 900 Hz maximum. both performs write '1' and '0' operation on "/sys/class/gpio/gpio192/value" device file.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve such a high frequency without consuming a lot of resource.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing an infinite loop in a kernel thread, there is no room for anything else
to happen, except IRQ and maybe other kernel thread.

What you could do is either

- program a timer on your hardware and do your pin toggling in an interrupt
- replace udelay with usleep_range

I suggest doing thing progressively, and starting in the kHz range with usleep_range, and eventually moving to cust om  timer  + ISR

in either case, you will probably have a lot of jitter, and doing such gpio toggling may be a good idea on a DSP or a PIC, but is a waste of resources on ARM + Linux, unless you are hardware assisted with pwm capable gpio engine.

Comment: You may also need to recompile the kernel with a significantly higher `CONFIG_HZ` value to increase the rate of the timer interrupt.